# Is there an enhanced third-party firmware for Pentax SLR cameras?

Tags: pentax, chdk, firmware, firmware-hacks

I am wondering whether there is a kit for making software improvements to the Pentax K-x camera.

What I'm after is something akin to the [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com), which is a firmware enhancement for many Canon point-and-shoot models.

Comment: Seems on-topic to me -- this would fall under "using photographic equipment"

Comment: good. :] just didn't want to presume (as a new comer)

Comment: CHDK isn't exactly an SDK, although adding scripting capabilities is one of its cool features. I've edited the post to reflect this -- hope you don't mind!

Comment: not at all - if it increases the chances that someone will know what I'm on about. I would be happy with something that provides programmatic access to the existing firmware. I'm not necessarily seeking to replace the firmware with anything else, I just want to automate some tasks, as is possible with CHDK.

Comment: What tasks do you want to automate?

Comment: There's a few things I'd like to try: (1)timelapse photography, (2)bulb photograph (i.e. like for fireworks) but without having to press the shutter release button manually, (3) take a sequence of images in successive depths of focus to allow (with image registration software?) to get better depth of field with macro photos.(4) lightning :)

Answer (score 3):

I've also tried to find a CHDK-like software for Pentax, probably the best Pentax firmware hack project is [Pentax Hack](http://www.pentax-hack.info/).

They were able to decrypt several Pentax firmwares, and modify a few things, like turning on debug mode.

Although the project supports several Pentax DSLRs, unfortunately it does not support K-x.

Comment: +1 That's all that I've ever found too... Mind you, I wouldn't do this on my current active camera. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/6-pentax-dslr-discussion/250555-resurrecting-pentax-firmware-hacking-35.html

There is a guy who named himself "shodan", putting effort into completely hacking the current Pentax DSLR firmwares...

here is the link to his github-page:

https://github.com/i-am-shodan/PHDK